# Conversion of Scala class to javascript using jscala

Tags: javascript, scala

I am a newbie to Scala and JScala. I have a Scala class with globals defined as `val test = Set("testglobal")`. My code to convert this to javascript is as following:

```
object Convertscalatojs {
  def converttoscala() {
    @Javascript class TrafficSource {
      val test = Set("test")
      //
      val test1="testvar"
    }

    val js = TrafficSource.jscala.javascript
    js.eval()
    println(js.asString)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    converttoscala()
  }
}
```

I am getting an error as:

```
Error:(14, 6) Unsupported syntax: scala.this.Predef.Set.apply[String]. 
    @Javascript class TrafficSource {
```

How do I convert the globals to JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `@JavaScript` annotation just means that a constructor for an equivalent type will be available in `javascript` code blocks. Such as the following:

```scala
@Javascript class StaticGlobalsReference {
    val test = Set("test")
}
```

Which can then be used in code blocks:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val js = javascript {
        val globals = new StaticGlobalsReference();
        println(globals.test);
    }
    println(js.asString);
}
```

Reference: http://jscala.org/